# What is the 102 MB partition in my Dell XPS17 for

Tags: dell-xps

What is the 102 MB partition in my Dell XPS17 for.

It contains stuff like this:

```
DIAGS/
AUTOEXUS.UP
CONFIG.UP
COPYUP
etc etc
```

It currently shows as D:. Can I delete it?

I can't see my other 2nd HD with is 500GB

Answer (score 1):

That's the *Dell Utility Partition*, see http://www.goodells.net/dellutility/

You can for sure delete it, if you won't need it. Every single one of these tools are available for download on Dell's website, too.

Comment: ok, but what if I want to do a factory reset again, theres a 20G partition which contains the factory image, and I think the utility partition allows me to use it..